# Unknown column 'base64str' in 'field list' But field exists in Database and everywhere

Tags: mysql, node.js, base64

I keep getting this as Error

```
D:\node_apps\financeplus>node financeplus.js
App running on Port: 7000
D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'base64str' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
    at D:\node_apps\financeplus\financeplus.js:77:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (D:\node_apps\financeplus\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:82:7) {
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'base64str' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO financeplusacct (fullname, address, city,state, tel,email,nationalID,gender,birth_date, bal, ccy, accNum, base64str) VALUES ('Allen Hommer','102 Whitewater Road','Smithfield','North Carolina','(919)800-3322','a.hommer@aol.com','A89360','Male','2021-11-03','2500','USD','00343515949','data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD.........')"
}

D:\node_apps\financeplus>
```

The information is not saved to the Mysql Database. I have created the tables to accomodate base64str And just adding it, it gives me that Error

the code to insert to Database

```
app.post('/api/createaccount',function(req,res){

var prologue = '00343';
var digits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000;
var accNum = prologue + digits;

var fullname = req.body.fullname;
var address = req.body.address;
var city = req.body.city;
var state = req.body.state;
var tel = req.body.tel;
var email = req.body.email;
var nationalID = req.body.nationalID;
var gender = req.body.gender;
var birth_date = req.body.birth_date;
var bal = req.body.bal;
var ccy = req.body.ccy;
var base64str = req.body.base64str;


dbConn.query('INSERT INTO financeplusacct (fullname, address, city,state, tel,email,nationalID,gender,birth_date, bal, ccy, accNum, base64str) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[fullname, address, city,state, tel,email,nationalID,gender,birth_date, bal, ccy, accNum, base64str], function (error, results, fields){
    if (error) throw error;
    return res.send({error: false,data: results, message: 'Account setup Complete'})
    });
});
```

Now Calling the REST api from React JS front end like this

```
function createCustomerAcc(){
      let base64str = localStorage.getItem('postImage');
    let item = {fullname, address, city, state, tel, email, nationalID, gender, birth_date, bal,ccy, base64str};
    fetch('http://localhost:7000/api/createaccount',{
        method : 'POST',
        mode : 'cors',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(item)
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) =>{
        if(responseJson.message =='Account setup Complete'){
            alert('Account Setup Complete');
        }else{
            alert(responseJson.message);
        }
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error(error);
    })
}
```

Gives me that Error in console. Why is this so? Please what do I have to do in this case? Its firing back the MySQL Error, and I dont get to see where the challenge comes from as even the column exists in the Database. Aand the funny thing is, the Column exists in all areas. Please what am I not getting right?

**Edits**

The CREATE Table is given as

```
CREATE TABLE `financeplusacct` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `nationalID` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ccy` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `bal` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `accNum` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `base64str` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE financeplusacct;`

Comment: @Barmar pls see Edits

Comment: "Unknown column..." can't be clearer. Please check you are viewing the right table in the right database. And see if that field really exists or not.